# How would I show an image, with automatic container 'framing', but with some hidden overage?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Using react/jsx.

I know that `backgroundSize: "cover"` will use the smallest extent of an image for resizing while keeping aspect ratio. So a wide image will use it's height to fit a portrait/phone-shaped space.

`transform: "scale(1.5)"`increases the size of the image along with the constraints of it's container. Translation (movement) animations based on the above example can only move left right as the top and bottom are pinned to the container.

What I need is the `cover` effect of calulating image size based on it's container, but with the image larger than the container. My images vary in size and are being read into an array by react. I need it to automatically resize these images to the resulting size with the end goal of being able to use various `@keyframe` animated movement on the images.

How would I tell css to "reduce the image to `cover` the container, maintaining aspect ratio, but leave it an arbitrary 25% oversize"?

Alternatively, could I do something here with JS/React?

I have some flexibility, so I can add/change elements or components with styles if I need to.

Comment: hello, did you take a look at object-fit and object-position ? transform has also transform-origin ...

Comment: @G-Cyrillus object-fit leaves the same issue. The image/object goes exactly to the extents of the box. I need to specify that the unknown size contained object keeps the aspect ratio, but results larger than the container.